# If Else block within while Loop in Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell script to iterate over a file with the below inputs. The file is named input.json

test,v1,yes

test2,v2,yes

test3,v3,yes

The shell script looks for the value "yes" in a line and runs the if block to print a message . Similarly if value is not "yes" it should go in else block .
Problem I am facing is when executing the code the code goes into else block even if the value it finds is yes . Also it is just iterating one time but it should iterate over all the lines in the file.

My current Script is :

```
filename=input.json

while IFS= read -r line;
do
  variable1=$(awk -F',' '{print $3}')
    
  if [ "$variable1" == "yes" ];    
  then
   echo "Template deployment required"
  else
   echo "Template deployment not required"  
  fi
done < $filename
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the value of `$variable1` is not what you expect it to be. Print it in your else branch (`printf "[%s]\n" "$variable1"` or `printf "[%s]\n" "$variable1" | od`)

Comment: Note that you are never using `$line` anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the value of `$variable1` is not what you expect it to be. Print it in your else branch (`printf "[%s]\n" "$variable1"` or `printf "[%s]\n" "$variable1" | od`). Make sure there's only a single line in your input.

But anyway, this isn't really idiomatic. Instead, you'd check the exit code of awk directly:

```
  variable1=$(awk -F',' '{print $3}')
    
  if awk -F',' '$3 != "yes" {exit 1}'
  then
   echo "Template deployment required"
  else
   echo "Template deployment not required"  
  fi
```

Or do everything in awk directly:

```
awk -F',' '
$3 == "yes" {print "Template deployment required"}
$3 != "yes" {print "Template deployment not required"}
'
```

or

```
awk -F',' '
{
if ($3 == "yes") {print "Template deployment required"}
else {print "Template deployment not required"}
}
'
```

Comment: The output after adding `printf "[%s]\n" "$variable1"` is [yes yes] so it is getting printed twice , is it the problem with my while loop

Comment: It means that standard input of awk contains two lines. You didn't provide a file name, so awk will read from stdin